# R edit subset of data frame and override original row-values

Tags: r, dataframe, deployr

I have a dataframe, where I extract a certain subset:

```
tmp <- mtcars |> select(disp, hp)
```

then I make some data manipulation

```
tmp$disp <- tmp$disp*0
tmp$hp <- tmp$hp*2
```

Now I want to reintegrate the changes into the original
How?

Of course I could work on the original df in the first place but I just want to know how to replace all values from a df by a subset.

I want to keep the order of the column names and if possible I don't want to use any index.
I also assume there are use cases where the select query is long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is:

`mtcars <- mutate(mtcars, tmp)`

edit: add this solution, which could be more intuitive

`newdf <- mtcars |> mutate(tmp)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to select names in `mtcars` that match with names in `tmp` and then replace values.

```
mtcars[,names(tmp)] <- tmp
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6    0 220 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6    0 220 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4    0 186 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6    0 220 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8    0 350 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6    0 210 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: what's the difference between `mtcars[,names(tmp)] <- tmp` and `mtcars[names(tmp)] <-tmp`? I don't see any.

Answer (score 1):

Or instead of creating 'tmp',

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars <- mtcars %>%
     mutate(disp = disp*0, hp = hp*2)
```

---

Or in `data.table)

```
setDT(mtcars)[, c("disp", "hp) := .(0, hp *2)]
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
mtcars[c("disp", "hp")] <-  list(0, mtcars$hp*2)
```

Comment: `mtcars <- tmp` will produce a table with only two columns, instead, the OP wants to update `mtcars` with those values in `tmp`